# Is it possible to update Bokeh xaxis.major_label_overrides with CustomJS?

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I'm stuck with Bokeh CustomJS for whole week and would be so happy if anyone helps me out of this.

I'm creating interactive, standalone candlestick charts with Bokeh library, using CustomJS and want to know if I can update `xaxis.major_label_overrides` on every callback.

Candlesticks are plotted with index number on x-axis, making sure weekend gaps are removed. And with `Select` widget, I made it possible to change candlestick’s granularity by using CustomJS callback to change the source CDB(CBDs are separately created based on its granularity).

Then, what I want the chart to be like next is to change the xaxis dates in accordance with the granularity selected. Since the dates on the x-axis are replaced with the index numbers by  `xaxis.major_label_overrides`, I tried to update them when callback(granularity change) is triggered.

Here are the code which did not work out. (Without `xaxis.major_label_overrides` callback, it did work.) Since I have almost no experience with JS, I'm sure some JS codes are lethal to the expected functioning.

```
#--Omitted: Some codes to create DataFrames with different granularities--#

#CDS for plotting
source = ColumnDataSource(data=df_M5) #default source
source_M1 = ColumnDataSource(data=df_M1)
source_M5 = ColumnDataSource(data=df_M5)

#creating dictionary list for index substitutions
overridetime_M1 = {i: date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M') for i, date in enumerate(df_M1['time'])}
overridetime_M5 = {i: date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M') for i, date in enumerate(df_M5['time'])}



plt1 = figure()

#--Omitted: Some codes to draw candlesticks using source--#

#default x-axis overriding
plt1.xaxis.major_label_overrides = overridetime_M5


select = Select(title="Option:", value="M5", options=["M1", "M5"])
callback_granularity = CustomJS(args=dict(
                source=source, 
                source_M1=source_M1, 
                source_M5=source_M5, 

                overridetime=overridetime,
                overridetime_M1=overridetime_M1,
                overridetime_M5=overridetime_M5,

                select=select
                plt1=plt1
                ), code="""

                    var sdata = source.data;
                    var f = select.value;

                    var data_M1 = source_M1.data;
                    var data_M5 = source_M5.data;

                    var ot = overridetime;
                    var ot_M1 = overridetime_M1;
                    var ot_M5 = overridetime_M5;


                    if (f == "M1") {
                        for (var k in sdata) {
                            sdata[k] = [];
                            sdata[k] = data_M1[k];    
                        }
                        plt1.xaxis.major_label_overrides = overridetime_M1;

                    } else if (f == "M5") {
                        for (var k in sdata) {
                            sdata[k] = [];
                            sdata[k] = data_M5[k];    
                        }
                        plt1.xaxis.major_label_overrides = overridetime_M5;
                    };


                    source.change.emit();
                    plt1.change.emit();
                """)

        select.js_on_change('value', callback_granularity)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible:

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Select, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure()
p.circle(0, 0)

s = Select(options=[('no', 'Do not override'),
                    ('yes', 'Override')],
           value='no')

s.js_on_change('value',
               CustomJS(args=dict(x_axis=p.xaxis[0]),
                        code="x_axis.major_label_overrides = cb_obj.value === 'no' ? {} : {0: 'Hello'};"))

show(column(p, s))
```

The issue with your code is that you use `xaxis`. In Bokeh, it's a "splattable list" of axes (meaning, any attribute change or method call applies the action to every item in the list). But in BokehJS, it's a regular list of axes.

Comment: Just understood the importance of `p.xaxis[0]` in your code!
Appreciate your kindly help.